# Access forbidden! Error 403 on apache

Tags: apache-http-server, opensuse-12.2

I am trying to configure apache server on openSUSE 12.2. I am doing as shown in the manual here http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Linux_Apache_MySQL_PHP it works fine. When I try to access localhost/~myuser/website/html/index.html I am getting this message:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Apache needs to be able to access the files it serves. This is a common mistake made when doing the setup in root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the owner of the files and folders to the owner of Apache. It should get resolved.
Command will be like:

```
sudo chown apache-user:apache-group ~myuser/website/html/ -R
```

Also change the permission of the folder to 755

```
sudo chmod 755 ~myuser/website/html/ -R
```

Comment: Here is the reference from Mediawiki manual

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads#Check_directory_security